# Class instance clustering in object reference graph for multi-entries serialization

Tags: python, database, graph, serialization, object

My question is on the best way to cluster a graph of class instances around specifically marked objects (*objects* are the graph nodes and the references to each other are the directed edges of the graph). To better explain my question, let me explain my motivation:

I currently use a moderately complex system to serialize the data used in my projects:

- "marked" objects have a specific attributes which stores a "saving entry": the path to an associated file on disc (but it could be done for any storage type providing the suitable interface)
- Those object can then be serialized automatically (eg: `obj.save()`)
- The serialization of a marked object `'a'` contains implicitly all objects `'b'` for which `'a'` has a reference to, directly s.t: `a.b = b`, or indirectly s.t.: `a.c.b = b` for some object `'c'`

This basically define specific storage entries to specific objects. I then have "container" type objects that:

1. can be serialized similarly (in fact their are or can-be "marked")
2. they don't serialize in their storage entries the "marked" objects (with direct reference): if `a` and `a.b` are both marked, `a.save()` calls `b.save()` and stores `a.b = storage_entry(b)`

So, if I serialize `'a'`, it will serialize automatically all objects that can be reached from `'a'` through the object reference graph, possibly in multiples entries. That is what I want, and it usually provides the functionalities I need. However, there are some structural limitations to this approach:

1. the multi-entry saving can only works through direct connections in "container" objects, and
2. there are situations with undefined behavior such as if two "marked" objects `'a'`and `'b'` both have a reference to an unmarked object `'c'`. In this case my system will stores `'c'` in both `'a'` and `'b'` making an implicit copy which not only double the storage size, but also change the object reference graph after re-loading.

I am thinking of generalizing the process. Apart for the practical questions on implementation (I am coding in python, and use Pickle to serialize my objects), there is a general question on the way to attach (cluster) unmarked objects to marked ones.

So, my questions are:

- What are the important issues that should be considered? Basically why not just use any graph parsing algorithm with the "attach to last marked node" behavior.
- Is there any work done on this problem, practical or theoretical, that I should be aware of?

**Example of a simple object graph to serialize:**

[image]

Circles are objects and arrow references. Orange circles are marked objects.

When serializing `A`, object `B` to `E` should be serialized but not blue objects because they are not reachable from `A`. Now, `B` is serialized in its own entry (i.e. file) and the question is how to choose where to serialize objects `C` to `E`, to `A` or `B` entry?

Some thinking on this example:

- object `C` is only reachable from `A`, so its should be attached to it
- to reach `E`, it is necessary to pass by `B`, so `E` should be attached to `B`
- what about `D`? Because after serialization if `B` is loaded (and not `A`), `D` should also be loaded but not `A`. Thus `D` should be serialized in `B` entry.

**Note:**
I added the tag `database` because I think the answer might come from that fields, even if the question is not really.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a missing conceptual step going on here. An object reference is not the object itself. So, perhaps consider serializing object references, and don't serialize object *c* inside *a* or *b*, for example. Serialize object *c* outside of them, and you save space and processing time.

Edit:
Basically, it would work like this:

```
foreach(object reference in serializeable)
    serialize(object in global)
    serialize(object reference)
```

Then, when you deserialize, you just make the object reference point back to the correct object.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, I do want to serialize all objects reachable from a starting object. Eg: say we have `a` and `b` marked, and `a.b=b`, `a.c=c` and `b.c=c`. If I do `a.save()` then a, b and c should be serialized, a in a, b in b, and c in one (and only one) of them. So that if I later do `load(entry_of_a)` it retrieve everything. Now, I cannot serialize every objects (such as int, float, etc...) in separated entries, that would make too many of them.

Comment: That make me think: in the above example, if after saving a, I do `load(entry_of_b)`, which is possible, I should get `c` in `b.c`. That is one of the constraint that need to be respected. The generalization is complicated..., and might not have a global solution.

Comment: Basically, instead of saving `c` inside `a`, you save `c` globally, then you save a reference to it inside `a`. Think of it like an address for a letter. The address is not the house, just helps find the house.

Comment: You set your deserializer to be able to remember that `a` has a reference to `c` and when the deserializer finds `c`, it sets `a`'s reference to the newly reconstituted object.

Comment: What do you mean by saving c globally? In the case of file system, where would that be? [Note that marked objects are instance of self-made classes, and thus most of the content is stored in their attributes, i.e. in "sub-objects" `c`]

Comment: How are you saving `a` and `b`? Save `c` the same way.

Comment: `a` and `b` are marked which means they have an associated storage entry defined, but not `c`.

Comment: I know this is really late, but save `c` as well in the global storage, then have `a` and `b` point to `c`.

Comment: For the algorithm to work, you need to mark `c` as well.